# Cannot get extended metadata without a mode?

Tags: gracenote

Is it normal that sending a request for an artist metadata, using

```
<OPTION>
    <PARAMETER>SELECT_EXTENDED</PARAMETER>
    <VALUE>LINK,COVER,REVIEW,ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY,ARTIST_IMAGE,ARTIST_OET,MOOD,TEMPO</VALUE>
</OPTION>
```

Returns almost non of the information (cover and artist_oet come in mind), but adding SINGLE_BEST or SINGLE_BEST_COVER will return said informations?

Are metadata limited when not searching in SINGlE_BEST mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended metadata, such as mood, tempo, artist origin and so on, will only be returned when in SINGLE_BEST or SINGLE_BEST_COVER mode.